# Django / Model image field asks for default image

Tags: python, django

I do not want to add default image for my model in Django. But when I delete default image from the model it says image attribute has no file associated with it. How should I fix it that it would not ask for the image when user does not add an image?

```
class MainPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name= ('Başlık'))
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name= ('Yazı'))
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpg',upload_to = 'images',blank=True,null=True,verbose_name = ('Resim'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MainPost,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 500 or img.width > 500:
            output_size = (500,500)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're missing a step between `manage.py makemigrations` `manage.py migrate` and however you're testing the ImageField. If a default was specified before, it's possible there are entries in the db that have the default path still, and are unable to resolve if it doesn't exist.